# How can I add new key used in python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>py dictionary.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dictionary.py", line 7, in <module>
    stu = {'grade', grade(score1, score2)}
NameError: name 'grade' is not defined
```

I'd like to add a grade to the `students[i]`, a `NameError` occurred .

How can I fix this?

```
students = {}
with open("data.txt") as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
       name, score1, score2 = line.split()
       students[i] = {"name":name, "score1":int(score1), "score2":int(score2)}
       stu = {'grade', grade(score1, score2)}
       students[i].update(stu)
       i += 1

def grade(score1, score2):
    score = score1 + score2
    if(200>=score and 180 <= score):
        return "A"
    ...
    else:
        return "F"
```

Comment: Define the function before you try and call it.

Comment: One hint unrelated to your question, you can replace `200>=score and 180 <= score` with `180 <= score < 200`.  It's called operator chaining.

Answer (score 0):

`grade` is defined below the code that calls it, so Python hasn't inserted it in the name space yet.

You should define the `grade` function *before* you call it

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to key but it show `grade` function is not define, just do fix it by arranging code (function declaration first than do call)

```
students = {}

def grade(score1, score2):
    score = score1 + score2
    if(200>=score and 180 <= score):
        return "A"
    ...
    else:
        return "F"

with open("data.txt") as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
       name, score1, score2 = line.split()
       students[i] = {"name":name, "score1":int(score1), "score2":int(score2)}
       stu = {'grade', grade(score1, score2)}
       students[i].update(stu)
       i += 1
```

Comment: You probably also want to fix the minor syntax error: `stu = {'grade': grade(score1, score2)}`.